# Partial match fetch

Tags: magicalrecord

I want to perform `partial match` like the clause `LIKE` do in `SQL`.

In Magical Record, to look for values for a specified field, we use `findByAttribute`:

```
NSArray *productsFoundByTitle = [Product MR_findByAttribute:@"product_title" withValue:@"bags"];
```

The problem is that this will return only `exact matches` of `bags` in `product_title`. I want to return also `partial matches` so a value like : `mail bags` would also be returned.

How can I do that in MagicalRecord?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution I came with so far is the following: Grap all data, and find all `Partial matches` with `rangeOfString` function:

```
        NSArray *allResults = [Product MR_findAll];
        for (id element in allResults) {
            if ([[element valueForKey:@"product_title"] rangeOfString:@"bags" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {

           //I got a partial match, save this instance for later use
          }         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read up about predicates. There are key words you're looking for such as startswith, endswith, and like. Check out the [predicate programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html)

Comment: Yes, but I was looking for MagicalRecord built in solution. Thanx anyway.

Comment: MagicalRecord is a wrapper for core data. Your question is regarding built in functionality for which magical record does not need to reinvent, so it doesn't...